# ArrayIndexOutofBound in QUICK-SORT implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort, divide-and-conquer

I guess my code should work but it is throwing ArrayIndexOutofBounds exception in sort,partition and main methods.

Where I am wrong?

**Here is the code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuickSort 
{   
public void sort(int a[], int low, int high)
{

    if(low < high)
    {
        int q = partition(a, low, high);
        sort(a, low, q-1);
        sort(a, q+1, high);
    }
}
public int partition(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot=a[high];
    int i= (low-1);
    for(int j=low; j<=high-1 ;j++)
    {
        if (a[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;
            exchange(a[i], a[j]);
        }
    }   
    exchange(a[i+1], a[high]);
    return i+1;
}
public void  exchange(int v1,int v2)
{
    int var1=v1;
    int var2=v2;
    var1 = var1 + var2;  
    var2 = var1 - var2;  
    var1 = var1 - var2; 
    //System.out.println(var1);
    //System.out.println(var2);
}
public void printArr(int a[])
{
    int n=a.length;
    System.out.println("SORTED ARRAY");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i]);
        System.out.print("\t");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 
    QuickSort obj = new QuickSort();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Enter the no of elements in array");
    int n= sc.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter the elements of array");
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }


    obj.sort(arr, 1 , arr.length);
    obj.printArr(arr); 

    sc.close();
 }
}
```

**These are the errors in Eclipse**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>   at QuickSort.partition(QuickSort.java:17)
>   at QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.java:10)
>   at QuickSort.main(QuickSort.java:67)

Comment: Tip: `j <= high-1` is the same as `j < high`

Comment: @VinceEmigh's tip will prove to be quite appropriate here. Firstly, you are passing `arr.length` for arg `high`. Remember, arrays are 0-indexed, so trying to access arr.length will result in a NPE. You want to access `arr.length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling to `sort` from `main` with `arr.length` as `high` parameter, which you pass to `partition`.

In `partition` you do

```
int pivot = a[high];
```

which is actually

```
int pivot = a[a.length];
```

Indexes in `Array` are from `0` to `array size - 1`, that's what causing the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Change in `main`

```
obj.sort(arr, 1 , arr.length);
```

To

```
obj.sort(arr, 1 , arr.length - 1);
```

Comment: Same ArrayIndexOutofBounds exception. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code had several mistakes :

1. You used your arrays as if there were indexed from 1 to length. In Java, the first element is in [0]-cell, and the last in the [length-1]-cell
2. Your exchange method doesn't work : you were swapping local variables. In Java, if you call a method on two ints, the method copies the values of those variables given as input, and any modification you make inside the method won't affect the original variable. Solution : give the array as input of the method, with the two indices you want to swap.
3. That kind of swap (adding the two variables inside 1 ...) doesn't work if the two variables are actually the same. You need to filter that case. (The swap were you use a third variable doesn't require this filter)

As a design choice, when writing methods on arrays, the arguments (int[] array, int from, int to) are usually such that it is inclusive in the case of 'from', and exclusive in the case of 'to'. I also modified your code to fit this norm.

Fixing all of those, you get this code, which runs correcty on my own computer : (I marked modifications with "//There" comments)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuickSort {
public void sort(int a[], int low, int high) {

    if (low < high - 1) {
        int q = partition(a, low, high);
        sort(a, low, q);// There
        sort(a, q + 1, high);// There
    }
}

public int partition(int a[], int low, int high) {
    int pivot = a[high - 1];
    int i = (low - 1);
    for (int j = low; j < high - 1; j++) {
        if (a[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            exchange(a, i, j);
        }
    }
    exchange(a, i + 1, high - 1); // There
    return i + 1;
}

public void exchange(int[] tab, int i1, int i2) // There
{
    if (i1 != i2) {
        tab[i1] = tab[i1] + tab[i2];
        tab[i2] = tab[i1] - tab[i2];
        tab[i1] = tab[i1] - tab[i2];
    }
    // System.out.println(tab[i1]);
    // System.out.println(tab[i2]);
}

public void printArr(int a[]) {
    int n = a.length;
    System.out.println("SORTED ARRAY");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i]);
        System.out.print("\t");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    QuickSort obj = new QuickSort();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Enter the no of elements in array");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter the elements of array");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // There
    {
        arr[i] = sc.nextInt(); // There
    }

    obj.sort(arr, 0, arr.length); // There
    obj.printArr(arr);

    sc.close();
}
}
```